# Java equivalent of C# RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: java, c#, rsa

I am a newbie to Encryption algos and C# code.
I am trying to get some data which is being encrypted decrypted using RSA algo in C# code. Below is C# code. I can't find any similar library in Java, can you help me with getting a java equivalent for the same.

```
 public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, string keyContainerName, bool doOaepPadding = false)
    {
        return DoCryptoTransformation(data, true, keyContainerName, doOaepPadding);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, string keyContainerName, bool doOaepPadding = false)
    {
        return DoCryptoTransformation(data, false, keyContainerName, doOaepPadding);
    }

    private byte[] DoCryptoTransformation(byte[] data, bool encryption, string keyContainerName,
        bool doOaepPadding = false)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] processedData;
            RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
            CspParameters cspParams = CreateCspParameters(keyContainerName);

            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                processedData = encryption ? rsa.Encrypt(data, doOaepPadding) : rsa.Decrypt(data, doOaepPadding);
            }
            return processedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            string message = string.Format("RsaCryptoProvider: Failed to {0} data.", encryption ? "encrypt" : "decrypt");
            Logger.Error("{0}. Exception details: {1}", message, ex);
            throw new CryptoProviderException(message, ex);
        }
    }

    private static CspParameters CreateCspParameters(string keyContainerName)
    {
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = keyContainerName;
        cspParams.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
        cspParams.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        return cspParams;
    }
}
```

The methods used which I want to redefine implementation for in java:

```
var previousKey = _encryptionService.RsaDecrypt(Key, CoreSettings.Instance.KeyContainerName);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have a read of the [Java security docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html), particularly the [JCA reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html). Then look at the millions of examples on stackoverflow and across the 'net.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKPolk, but that will give me all of the features Java has for RSA encryption-decryption. I would first want to know how RSACryptoServiceProvider works and then what are parallels to draw

Comment: Such a question is simply too broad for stackoverflow, sorry.